# skip feedexport when exception occured

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Is it possible to only export the extracted items if no exception was thrown during the crawl?
I run into errors from time to time but I need to make sure the crawl was successfully completed before processing the exported items.

I am using [scrapy-feedexporter-sftp](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-feedexporter-sftp)
and made the configration in settings as described in the README.
The upload to sFTP works.

To produce an error I am using a wrong XPATH

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 256, in xpath
    **kwargs)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 1582, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in td[1]//span//text()TEST_TEXT_TO_THROW_ERROR
```

The crawl failed but scrapy will push the file anyways:

```
[scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored json feed (59 items) in: sftp://user:pass@host/my/path/to/file/foo_2020-07-23T09-03-50.json
2020-07-23 11:03:54 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 581,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 24199,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 2.831581,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 23, 9, 3, 53, 763269),
 'item_dropped_count': 1,
 'item_dropped_reasons_count/DropItem': 1,
 'item_scraped_count': 59,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 86,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,  <------
 'log_count/INFO': 15,
 'log_count/WARNING': 2,
 'memusage/max': 60858368,
 'memusage/startup': 60858368,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 23, 9, 3, 50, 931688)}
2020-07-23 11:03:54 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Regards ;)

Comment: Can you please provide sample code so I can have a look at it?

Comment: i have added more details

Comment: I cannot think of a straight way to achieve this. What I can think of is: (1) exporting to a local file, (2) running the spider with https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#std-setting-CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT set to 1, and (3) have a separate script that delivers the items only if the spider exited without errors.